# Accessing an external webservice via VPN through NAT reflection times out

Tags: networking, raspberry-pi, routing, strongswan

I have a Raspberry Pi 4B with Raspbian arm64 on it running a Strongswan VPN server alongside multiple services that I can access frow WAN via my external IP/my domain name. I use NAT reflection on my router so that I can use those same services from my LAN. The VPN routing seems to be working correctly, as I can access the internet and any devices on the LAN from any VPN device. Similarly, I can also ping any VPN device from my LAN.

The problem arises when I try to access my web services via my domain name. The same services that I am normally able to access from both LAN and WAN are inaccessible for my VPN devices. If I forward a port of a different device on the LAN and try to access that on a VPN device via the domain name then that works just fine. As such, the routing and NAT reflection of my network setup both seem to be fine. It's only when I try to access websites hosted on the same server as the VPN via the domain name/external IP (accessing websites via the local IP works fine) that things don't work as expected.

I conclude that something goes wrong on the routing side of things of my Raspberry Pi, however I am clueless as to where to begin debugging. As such, I'm not sure which configuration files would by useful to post here. I'll be happy to send any furter information that is necessary to help me solve this issue.

My Strongswan config:

```
conn ikev2-rsa
    auto=add
    compress=no
    type=tunnel
    keyexchange=ikev2
    fragmentation=yes
    forceencaps=yes

    dpdaction=clear
    dpddelay=300s

    left=%any
    leftid=@example.com (this is set to my real domain name)
    leftcert=strongswan-cert.pem
    leftsendcert=always
    leftsubnet=0.0.0.0/0,::/0

    right=%any
    rightid=%any
    rightauth=pubkey
    rightsourceip=10.2.1.0/24
    rightdns=10.0.0.4
    rightsendcert=never
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with a solution that works for me, so I'd like to post it here, just in case someone comes across the same problem.

The idea is to make the server accept the public IP as its own to stop forwarding packets any further. This means that you can access the server via the domain name even when you're connected to the VPN.

The flaw of this approach, is that all the traffic destined for your public IP address will stop at your server. So in the case that you have port-forwarding set up for multiple devices on the same WAN address, you will not be able to access them via the VPN anymore, as the traffic never reaches your router. I'm willing to accept this compromise, as I rarely access other devices than this server via my external IP address, especially when using the VPN. You should, however, be aware of this and see if it works in your case as well.

To accomplish this, I have written a bash script that accepts two positional arguments - the interface you want to assign your public IP address to and your domain name. The usage could thus for example be:

```
sudo ~/externalIP.sh eth0 example.com
```

This script should be ran on startup as well as periodically, just in case your IP address changes. It is important that the script is ran by root, for example using the root user's crontab:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

An example, which runs every hour and at startup looks like this:

```
0 * * * * /home/user/externalIP.sh eth0 example.com
@reboot /home/user/externalIP.sh eth0 example.com
```

Finally, the code for the script is as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash
lookup=($(nslookup $2 | grep -oP '(?<=Address:\s)\d+(.\d+){3}')) # look up my address
if [[ "${#lookup[@]}" -ne "2" ]]; then # exit if the address could not be found
        exit
fi
address="${lookup[1]}/32"
addresses=($(ip addr show dev $1 | grep -oP '\d+(.\d+){3}/32')) # get addresses assigned to my interface
exists=0
for i in "${addresses[@]}"
do
        if [[ "$i" = "$address" ]]; then # check if the address already exists
                exists=1
        elif ! [[ "$i" =~ ^((10)|(192\.168)|(127)|(172\.1[6-9])|(172\.2\d)|(172\.3[0-1]))\. ]]; then # remove superfluous public addresses
                $(ip addr del $i dev $1)
        fi
done
if [[ "$exists" -eq 0 ]]; then # add address if it does not exist yet
        $(ip addr add $address dev $1)
fi
```

In detail, the code looks up your public address and appends it to the specified interface. It also removes all previously added public addresses. This code has a few safeguards built-in, to make sure that no matter what, your private IP addresses will remain untouched.

Don't forget to make it executable:

```
sudo chmod u+x ~/externalIP.sh
```